# getting all instances of IFoo from MEF aggregatecatalog in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mef

I am sure this cant be hard - can it?

the only function seems to be GetExports but that seems to take 2 generic parameters plus a ExportDefintion that itself takes 5 values including a lambda - surely not? I thought I could do something like `agcat.GetExports<IFoo>()`

Comment: Can't say for sure (since I haven't quite figured out how shared instances work), but I don't think MEF is really setup to easily do this (if at all).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't get instances from a catalog you get them from a container.

```
var container = new CompositionContainer(agCat);
var foos = container.GetExports<IFoo>(); // Or GetExportedValues<IFoo>()
```